# command to retrieve the parent directory name if file doesn'texists in child directory in linux

Tags: linux

Get the directory name as output(`19.08`) when `final.txt` doesn't appears in `trans` sub folder. Main parent directory  names( `19.02,19.04,19.06`) keeps changing. But the subfolder names(`base and trans`) are always same and `final.txt` always will be available only under `trans` folder.

When the `final.txt` is not available under the trans folder it should return the 19.08 as output in linux/shell?

Please suggest on this

```
     |--Project
        |-- 19.02
        |   |-- base
        |   |-- trans
                -- final.txt
        |-- 19.04
        |   |-- base
        |   |-- trans
                -- final.txt
        |-- 19.06
        |   |-- base
        |   |-- trans
                -- final.txt
        |-- 19.08
            |-- base
            |-- trans
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure find solution, based on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196960/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file):

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1"/trans/final.txt' -- {} ';' -print | 
# remove the leading Project from path
xargs -n1 basename
```

1. Find directories that are exactly two level down
2. For each entry execute `test -e <entry>/trans/final.txt` - ie. check if final.txt exists
3. If it does not `'!'` exist, then `-print` the path.
4. The `| xargs -n1 basename` is used to transform `./Project/19.08` into just `19.08`.

My first solution using `comm` and creating lists, with comments in code:

```
# Create an MCVE
mkdir -p Project/19.0{2,4,6,8}/{base,trans}
touch Project/19.0{2,4,6}/trans/final.txt

# Extract only unique lines from the first list
# So the folders which do not have final.txt in them
comm -23 <(
    # Create a list of all Project/*/ folders
    find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 |
    sort
) <(
    # Create a list of all Project/*/*/final.txt files
    find . -mindepth 4 -maxdepth 4 -name final.txt -type f |
    # Extract only Project/*/ part, so twice dirname
    xargs -n1 dirname | xargs -n1 dirname |
    sort
) | 
# Remove the leading 'Project' name
xargs -n1 basename
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamil Cuk. i just want to ignore .git folder search when i use this command. I just updated the command like this,` find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d '!' -path '*/\.git/*' -exec sh -c 'test -e "$1"/trans/final.txt' -- {} ';' -print | xargs -n1 basename` its giving me output as `19.02 19.04 19.06` how to get the opposite of this scenario(not of the current output)?

Comment: You applied `!` only to `-path`. You need to apply `!` to `-path` and then `'!' -exec ...`.

Answer (score 2):

This script will print all directory names in Project that don't contain a file `trans/final.txt`.

```
# The trailing / makes sure we loop over directories only
for DIR in Project/*/
do
     # additional condition "if [ -d "$DIR" ] &&..." is not necessary because of the trailing / above
     if [ ! -f "${DIR}/trans/final.txt" ]
     then
         # basename removes both the trailing / and the parent dir
         basename "$DIR"
     fi
done
```